# Instrumenting files on the fly with Istanbul

Tags: node.js, istanbul, nyc

I can instrument a file/folder and write it to disk like so:

```
$ istanbul instrument public --output public-coverage  --embed-source true
```

however I am wondering if there is a way to instrument files on the fly and serve them to the browser without ever writing the instrumented files to disk. Something like this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    const file = req.path; // whatever
    const k = cp.spawn('istanbul', ['instrument']);
    fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(k.stdin).pipe(res);
});
```

does anyone know if that's possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is.

Below is an example where I'd just intercept the request for a normal "main.js" file and return the "instrumented" version instead.
Just a proof of concept, without any error handling and only for a specific file, but I think you get the point.

Alternatively you can load up instanbul in your code "require("istanbul")" and perform the action without actual spawns

```
app.get("/main.js", (req, res, next) => {
  const cmd = path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", ".bin", "istanbul");
  const file = path.join(__dirname, "public/main.js");
  const s = spawn(cmd, ["instrument", file, "--embed-source", "--no-compact", "--preserve-comments"]);

  s.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: you could pipe the data to the response stream, I think you mean res.write() not res.send()

Comment: true that, although in above example it has pretty much the same outcome. But as mentioned just a proof of concept. Point is, if you omit the --output attribute, istanbul will generate the output on stdout thus removing the need for file persistance